# I have data in below format and i want to calculate the employees date break time and total date time spend in the office

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

First table [First table which sync with machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQqDw.png)  and this is second table [Once data is inserted it will invoke the trigger and inserted into second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Om7j.png)

friends can you please help me with this...

I have written below query but not able to calculate the proper break time.

```
alter procedure sp_get_Attendance_salary_report     

@name varchar(500),      
@lname varchar(500),      
@fromDate varchar(500),      
@toDate  varchar(500),      
@eid  varchar(500)    

as      
begin      
declare @sqlcommand varchar(8000);    

set @sqlcommand='select 
 te.EmployeeId as [Employee Id],    
        (te.name+'' ''+te.lname) Names,    
        tsom.Shiftdate as [ShiftDate],    
        datename(dw,tsom.Shiftdate) as [Week Day],    
        convert(varchar(50),tsom.InTime,109) as [In time],    
        convert(varchar(50),tsom.OutTime,109) as [Out Time],    
       convert(varchar(5),(Convert(time,tsom.OutTime - tsom.InTime ,8)),8)as [Total Working Hours],
       shift_hours
            into #temp_time
     from  dbo.tbl_emp_shift_ot_mapping tsom    
     inner join tblEmployee te  on  te.EmployeeId=tsom.emp_id 
     inner join tbl_shift_timing tst on tst.id=tsom.shift_id
     where  tsom.emp_id<>convert(int,'''')'    

 if(@name <> '' )    
 begin    
   set @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ' and te.name like ''%'+@name+'%'''    
 end    


 if( @lname <> ' ')    
 begin    
   set @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ' and te.lname like ''%'+ @lname+'%'' '      
 end     

if (@todate <> '')  and ( @fromDate <>'' )        
begin           
set @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ' and tsom.shiftdate  >= CONVERT(date,'''+@fromDate+''',104) and tsom.shiftdate <= CONVERT(date,'''+@todate+''',104) '          
end      

 if(@eid <> 0 )    
 begin    
   set @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ' and te.employeeId = '''+@eid+''''    
 end    
       set @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand +' order by tsom.InTime desc';
       set @sqlcommand = @sqlcommand + '       select names,[Employee Id], 


    isnull(
     RIGHT(''0'' + CAST(  sum( (CAST(SUBSTRING([Total Working Hours], 1, CHARINDEX('':'', [Total Working Hours], 1)-1) AS INT)*3600+              
     CAST(SUBSTRING([Total Working Hours], CHARINDEX('':'', [Total Working Hours], 1)+1, 1000) AS INT)*60)) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),10) + ''.'' +          
   RIGHT(''0'' + CAST(( sum( (CAST(SUBSTRING([Total Working Hours], 1, CHARINDEX('':'', [Total Working Hours], 1)-1) AS INT)*3600+              
     CAST(SUBSTRING([Total Working Hours], CHARINDEX('':'', [Total Working Hours], 1)+1, 1000) AS INT)*60)) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2),0.00) 

     AS [Completed Hours],
     sum(shift_hours) [Estimated Hours]


    from  #temp_time

     group by names,[Employee Id] '

 exec (@sqlCommand)    


      print @sqlCommand



--exec @sqlCommand    
end 


id    User_ID   Event_Trigger   Time_Stamp
116203  66  IN  10/13/2016 07:07
116171  66  OUT 10/12/2016 16:24
116168  66  IN  10/12/2016 14:34
116155  66  OUT 10/12/2016 13:25
116124  66  IN  10/12/2016 06:44
116106  66  OUT 10/11/2016 16:51
116097  66  IN  10/11/2016 11:49
116096  66  OUT 10/11/2016 11:28
116078  66  IN  10/11/2016 07:17
116050  66  OUT 10/10/2016 16:25
116040  66  IN  10/10/2016 14:23
116030  66  OUT 10/10/2016 13:19
116006  66  IN  10/10/2016 07:00
115954  66  IN  10/08/2016 13:35
115899  66  OUT 10/08/2016 08:10
115878  66  IN  10/07/2016 16:18
115873  66  OUT 10/07/2016 14:21
115860  66  IN  10/07/2016 13:36
115832  66  OUT 10/07/2016 06:59
115803  66  IN  10/06/2016 16:39
```

Comment: Did you try anything. If yes, post whatever you tried so far

Comment: Also post the sample data in text format.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text, please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edit your Q and add sample table data,expected result, and what you try so far .

Comment: Please check and let me know if more details is needed... Please help me friends

Comment: what is your input and output? Data which is shown is input or output?

Comment: Input is first table i have attached screen shot of table. it takes the data from finger print machine.